# Is my proof using squeeze theorem correct?

Tags: solution-verification

I have to prove using squeeze theorem that limit of $(1.3.5...(2n-1))/(2.4.6...2n)$ tends to 0 as n tends to infinity.

My attempt:

$1/(2.4.6...2n)\leq u_n\leq ((1.3.5...(2n-1))/(2.2.2...2n)$, where $u_n$ is the given sequence.

Thus we have,
$1/(2.4.6...2n)\leq u_n\leq ((1.3.5...(2n-1))/2^{n}(n)$

Taking limit on both the sides, we get,

$0\leq lim u_n\leq 0$

Is this correct??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you heard of the Stirling's approximation?

Comment: No, I haven't heard of it!

Comment: Are you asking the limit of$ (2n-1)/2n$?

Comment: No I am asking to prove the limit of (1.3.5...(2n-1))/(2.4.6...2n)

Comment: Why do you think the limit of the right-hand side is 0?

Comment: Then what should I take my right hand side as?

Comment: This is a tricky problem.  Is it homework for a class?  Were you given a hint?  Was any similar problem discussed in class?

Comment: Hint: Can you discover $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that $u_n \leq n^{-\alpha}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$? Have in mind that you will be proving $u_n \leq n^{-\alpha}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by Mathematical Induction.